# Suspending an AutoHotkey combination when loaded

Tags: autohotkey

I'm using an AHK script which lets me map the number row of my laptop keyboard to the numpad, so that I can type the ALT-Codes. I have mapped it so that it is suspended/unsuspended with a special key combo: `^SC11E` (SC11E) being the ASCII code of a key on my Dell keyboard.

But, this creates a problem that when AHK first loads the script, the mapping is already done, thus I can't type the special characters like `!@#$%^&*()` without first Suspending the script.

Is there a way to load a script in the suspended state, or suspend a script just after loading.

This is my script:

```
; Remap Numpad
; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ErNQz5PC73c
; NumPad-CODE
; remapping "normal" number keys to make them
; behave like numpad numbers
0::Numpad0
1::Numpad1
2::Numpad2
3::Numpad3
4::Numpad4
5::Numpad5
6::Numpad6
7::Numpad7
8::Numpad8
9::Numpad9
;using the "Ctrl + Toggle Mousepad" to turn on/off remapping code
^SC11E::
Suspend,Toggle
return
```

What I've tried so far is manually sending the `!SC11E` combo at the end of the script like so:

```
...  ;code from previous snippet
return
Send ^{SC11E}  ;Try to suspend the script - 1st try
Send ^SC11E  ; Try to suspend the script - 2nd try
Suspend  ;Try to suspend the script - 3rd try
```

But none of these approaches work... How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [the documention](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/Suspend.htm):

> Any hotkey/hotstring subroutine whose **very first line is Suspend** (except Suspend On) will be exempt from suspension. In other words, the hotkey will remain enabled even while suspension is ON. This allows suspension to be turned off via such a hotkey.

```
suspend ; suspend hotkeys at start

0::Numpad0
1::Numpad1
2::Numpad2
3::Numpad3
4::Numpad4
5::Numpad5
6::Numpad6
7::Numpad7
8::Numpad8
9::Numpad9

SC11E::suspend
```

Comment: Thanks! that works. It's really a pain traversing that documentation, although after you've pointed it out I feel like *how did i miss that line?* :)